# Evaluating $\intop_{D}2x^{2}y-6x^{2}y^{2}+2x^{2}yz\,dx\,dy\,dz$, where $D$ is given by $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\leq1$

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

I've managed to calculate this integral

$$\intop_{D}\left(2x^{2}y-6x^{2}y^{2}+2x^{2}yz\right)dx\,dy\,dz$$

where $D$ is given by $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\leq1,$ by following the author's advice and converting it to spherical coordinates. However, it was extremely labourious and I'm wondering if I've missed any shortcuts. Could anyone please advise?

The initial conversion to spherical coordinates gave

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(2r^{5}\sin^{4}\phi\cos^{2}\theta\sin\theta\right)-\left(6r^{6}\sin^{5}\phi\cos^{2}\theta\sin^{2}\theta\right)+\left(2r^{6}\sin^{4}\phi\cos^{2}\theta\sin\theta\cos\phi\right)\right)dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$$ and eventually I reached

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(0-\left(3/14\right)\pi\sin^{5}\phi+0\right)d\phi=\frac{-8\pi}{35}.$$Is there a simpler method?

Comment: When you reached the final integral, you got that two of the terms are zero. Maybe you obtained that doing all computations but there is a quick way to see they must be zero: just notice that for any fixed $r, \phi$ the terms are an odd function with respect to $\theta$, integrated on $[0, 2\pi]$. By a change of variables $u = \theta - \pi$ you obtain the same integral but in a symmetric interval. Any integral of an odd function on a symmetric interval is zero.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks. Why do I also get the right answer if I ignore the $2x^{2}y$ and $2x^{2}yz$ terms in my original integral even though the latter is not an odd function.

Comment: @Daniel - on reflection, $2x^{2}yz$ is an odd function in $y$. Is that correct?

Comment: It is correct. Since you already wrote the expression in terms of spherical coordinates, I made the observation of the function being odd in this context. You can use the same argument before using spherical coordinates by making first the integral in terms of $y$.

Comment: @Daniel - If you have the time and inclination, I'd be happy to accept your comments as an answer.